# Как в postman отправить запрос на сервер в виде объекта через form-data

Tags: postman, formdata

Как отправить такой JSON объект через form-data

```json
{
    "data": {
        "video": "vidoe"
    }
}
```

Вот так не работает, если отправлять через form-data, а через x-www-form-urlencoded работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: API к которому делаю запросы сделано на Strapi

Comment: Покажите как работает?